Is it possible to do clustering using single IP address but different ports having config given below?
1st instance:
node {
    name = "emqx1@127.0.0.1"
    cookie = "emqxsecretcookie"
    data_dir = "data"
}

cluster {
    name = emqxcl
    discovery_strategy = static
    static {
        seeds = ["emqx1@127.0.0.1", "emqx2@127.0.0.1"]
    }
}

dashboard {
    listeners.http {
        bind = 18090
    }
}

2nd instance:
node {
    name = "emqx2@127.0.0.1"
    cookie = "emqxsecretcookie"
    data_dir = "data"
}

cluster {
    name = emqxcl
    discovery_strategy = static
    static {
        seeds = ["emqx1@127.0.0.1", "emqx2@127.0.0.1"]
    }
}

dashboard {
    listeners.http {
        bind = 18095
    }
}

I am trying to do clustering in mqtt emqx with single IP address using different ports(127.0.0.1 or may be system IP address).when I am starting any one instance of emqx the other instance is not starting, showing error..
The log is  [error] ssl:default failed to listen on 8883 - eaddrinuse (address already in use).

Your test will be failing because both instances are attempting to listen for incoming connections on port 8883 (default port for MQTT over SSL/TLS is 8883). How are users going to connect to your cluster? (i.e. if they connect to 127.0.0.1:8883 then only one thing can be listening; that could be a load balancer but that complicates things a bit!). You may be able to have separate configs for each node but, if this is a test, it may be simpler to run the nodes in containers (e.g. Docker).

What if I specify the ports like this?
static {
seeds = ["emqx1@127.0.0.1:180090", "emqx2@127.0.0.1:18095"]
}
is it possible?

That's another issue :-). This section of the docs covers some of the ports you would need to change (and I have no idea if you can configure each server to use different ports).

The issue is that you are not altering the port number of your broker's mqtt/tls; instead, you are only modifying the port number for the dashboard. For mqtt/tls, the default port number is 8883. Additionally, in order to cluster your emqx, make sure your broker has the same version for compatibility issues and update the port number for SSL in one or both of your emqx instances (you can do this via the emqx dashboard or emqx.conf).
